# Hiding element with v-show and rendering it back with a keydown event in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a div containing icons that I am hiding with a boolean value and v-show directive:

```
<div class="room" v-show=show.room  @click='toggle = !toggle'>
       <div class="col-lg-6 draw-icon-container" v-show="toggle">
        <p>Show</p>
      </div>
      </div>

data: () => ({
    toggle: true,
  }),
```

The desired div gets hid by clicking on it, but since it is removed I have no way to display it back, how can I render it again after the user has pressed the enter key? Something like this:

```
               if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                 this.toggle = false
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: {room: true},
    toggle: true
  },
  created: function () {
    // listen for key event
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this.toggleMethod)
  },
  methods: {
    toggleMethod() {
      this.toggle = true;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="room" v-show=show.room  @click='toggle = !toggle' style="background:red;width:100%;height:40px;">
 <div class="col-lg-6 draw-icon-container" v-show="toggle">
  <p>Show (Click me to toggle show/hide)</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

To access the scoped variable of the vue component that defined in `data()`, you must use `this` keyword, hence to change the value of `toggle`, you must use `this.toggle = false`

Comment: I tried that too, forgot to paste it correctly, however it is still not working

Comment: Ah I see! So why don't just click the `div` again to show it? I updated my answer with your code & it works. Just need to define some style for the parent div so that we can click back to show its child div again.

Comment: If you really need to listen for key event, add the global key event with `window.addEventListener`, see my code example above.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Any idea how to make it work on firefox as well?

Comment: Maybe you can try `document.addEventListener` instead of `window.addEventListener`?